# Is there a D2L Valence API for SSO (Single Sign-on)?

Tags: desire2learn

Sorry, I'm just new with Valence API and I was reading all the forums and blogs of valence and have not seen anything or a code snippets on how this is done using Valence API. We have a Parent webapp (parents register and pay their school fees), from this webapp we want Parents to utilize the Parent Auditor functionality of D2L by allowing them to SSO using their credentials going to their Auditor homepage (by-passing D2L Login page). I was able to do with valence api to register/enroll them in D2L LMS as auditor role and their audittee (chidren). Can you provide a code snippets how I could do the SSO part after I enrolled them through valence api? Is there really such thing as SSO for valence?

Answer (score 0):

We have something like this that is currently only available to internal apps. I will find out why it is restricted, and can find out what it would take to get it opened up.